# Apple magic mouse only works on surfaces that are slightly reflective after 10.8.2 update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, mouse

My magic mouse suddenly stopped tracking on the mousepad I have been using for a month now. Everything about the mouse works (gestures, clicking, etc) except tracking. Strangely enough, the mouse tracks perfectly on my MacBook Pro's surface. I have checked the battery contacts, optics, and have replaced the batteries, to no avail. This issue only appeared after I updated to 10.8.2. The mouse only has issues tracking with non-reflective surfaces, everything else works as smoothly as before. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I have been having the same problem and it is infuriating. I have just bought this iMac 27" and I cannot believe that I chose the magic mouse instead of the trackpad. This problem just started out of the blue and I have done all the usual troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  It just stopped working on my mousepad about 20 minutes ago, but works on the desk and other hard surfaces.  I don't know if it's reflectivity or not.  I suspect it might be due to a cloudy lens or something.  In my case there was no indication of any issue, it just stopped tracking.